# Is there is any restriction in asking permissions in android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I tried to ask permission for contacts, and the user denied 2 times app didn't ask for the third time.
Is there is any restriction in asking for permission to access contacts?

```
val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(mActivity)
builder.setTitle("Read Contacts permission")
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null)
builder.setMessage("Please enable access to contacts.")
builder.setOnDismissListener {
    requestPermissions( mActivity, arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS), 1 ) 
}
builder.show()
```

Comment: On android 10 and below there's an option to "never ask again", on [android 11](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/permissions#dialog-visibility) it's implied when user denies permission twice.

Comment: @Pawel Thanks man.